# How to create a controlled Fabric UI TextField component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I've been trying to code a controlled TextField component in the standard way just like in React docs:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
            text: event.target.value
    });
}

<TextField label='Enter Text' value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

The code above is what I've been using, but it seems that it doesn't change the state of the react component, because in the same form if I change a controlled checkbox, it resets the textfield to be empty. If I use a standard html input element it works just as expected and doesn't clear the field.

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't TextField work the same way as a text type input?

Comment: put `console.log(event.target.value)` inside handleChange function and check the value, it should work.

Comment: Tried that and for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: what the value it is printing?

Comment: Doesn't print anything :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/textfield), `onChange` is not a property. Use `onChanged` instead. Note that the return value is the textfield's value, not an event.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out 10 minutes ago I was in the process of answering but you were faster so I'll accept it.

Comment: Wow, this took me forever to find out.  Their documentation needs to be clearer...

Answer (score 1):

According to this [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/TextField/examples/TextField.Basic.Example.tsx):

```html
handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({
            text: value
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also I don't see an example in there for a controlled TextField, I've looked at this before asking the question. I've had a similar problem trying to implement a Checkbox but for that Microsoft provides a proper example: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Checkbox/examples/Checkbox.Basic.Example.tsx but unfortunately for TextField I found no solution.

Comment: Have you bound your `handleChange` into your component ?

Comment: Yes I have. ( in the constructor after initializing state `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you want to do
but ... If what you need is to pass the input value to a text label, you can do it this way:

First you must declare an interface outside of your class

```
interface myState {
  value1: string;
}
```

you must include your Interface in the class.

```
class TextFieldControlledExample extends React.Component<{}, myState> {...}
```

I suppose that for TypeScript themes you must publicly declare the interface of which you are using.

```
public state: myState = { value1: ''};
```

you must declare a function within the render to assign the value of the state

```
public render() {
    const { value1 } = this.state;
```

in this way you assign the value of your inputs. but to update it you have to create a function and call it on the onChange

```
<TextField
  label="Enter Text"
  value={this.state.value1}
  onChange={this._onChange}
  styles={{ fieldGroup: { width: 300 } }}
/>
<Text  variant='xxLarge' nowrap block>
  {value1}
</Text>
```

to assign the input value to the state you have declared using setState. must do a function.

```
  private _onChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) => {
    this.setState({ value1: newValue || '' });
  };
```

You can see the example working here
https://codepen.io/jasp402/pen/EBWBgO